# Lenovo Ideapad 330 - most of bootups end with black screen

Tags: arch-linux, amd-graphics, amd

We recently bought a Lenovo [Ideapad 330-15ARR](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330-14igm_330-15igm_330-15icn_330-15arr_330touch-15arr_hmm_201805.pdf) (81D200DDPB) and I tried to install [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) on it. This PC has an AMD 3 2200U CPU and AMD Radeon Vega 3 GPU.

Most of the boot ups end with a black screen. I first see the Lenovo splash logo, then there's the "starting version xxx" message from systemd, and then I would expect to see the display manager ([GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM) in this case). But, in about 80% of the time, instead I see a black screen. It is probably not "completely off", as I see that it actually is illuminated and it most likely is displaying an all-black image.

Important fact; the very same thing happens with the vanilla Arch Linux installation media (USB pen drive in my case). It ends up with black screen most of the time too.

The system is fully upgraded as of today.

When it actually boots properly everything seems to work fine and I can do whatever I want, but when it ends with black screen, there is nothing I can do. I tried switching virtual TTY with `Ctrl + Alt + Fx`, but this just doesn't change anything. The only important thing I tried is to disable Wayland for GNOME/GDM, but this did not make any difference.

Any pointers how should I get to the root cause of this problem and solve it?

Comment: @K7AAY - how can dmesg help if it is only for the current boot? In the failed boot I cannot access dmesg at all. I've browsed through journalctl output for the failed boot, but there is no explicit error in there. I just suddently stops in the middle of boot and doesn't go any further.

Comment: OK, it stops. What was it doing right before it stopped? As to the AMD Graphics Driver, I don't have an answer, because _Warning: Arch Linux is officially not supported_  as  per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Loading

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Lenovo_Ideapad_330_(Ryzen)#Kernel) (although the information is applicable to all Linux distros) the *amdgpu* module may fail to load due to a race condition if it's not included in the initramfs, which is why you're sometimes encountering a black screen.

When using Arch installation medium, make sure *linux-firmware* is installed and add the `amdgpu` module in your mkinitcpio config file:

```
MODULES=(amdgpu ...)
```